# How to save data against each user core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I am trying to my data set to Core data. I could successfully save the data in coreData.

mY application have login. So, I need to save data against each user.
Now I visible the whole data foe every user.
 Is there any idea for save user specific.

Comment: You will need to switch the sqlite backing file for each user.

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for your business logic.

One one hand, I suspect you have data that is available for everyone, you do not need to protect these.

For entities where the access should be restricted, you can store information about valid users or user groups in an attribute or a relationship. If you want to display a list of entities of that kind to the user, you have to fetch the data with some `NSPredicate` which gets you only the entities of the user, like so:

```
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(user = %@) and (exampleAttr = 42)", currentUser];
```